# Notarial Deed Translation from Canadian English

Tags: sentence, translation, legalese, government

I have to translate an English document from Quebec into Polish language. However, there is one sentence that I cannot understand:

> As the whole now subsists with all its rights members and
>   appurtenances, without exception or reserve of any kind on the part of
>   the Vendor

Can somebody please help me and translate the sentence above into understandable English?

Context:

> With a building thereon erected bearing the civic number 5*** and 5***
>   of said Ch****** Street, and whereof the south-westerly wall is
>   mitoyen.
>
> Subject to a reciprocal servitude of view as created in deed
>   registered at Mo****** under the number 1******.
>
> As the whole now subsists with all its rights members and
>   appurtenances, without exception or reserve of any kind on the part of
>   the Vendor

After last sentence the next paragraph begin.

Comment: That is a clausal adjunct, not a sentence. Could you provide more context, please? That will make it easier to explain how this relates to the sentence of which it is a part.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response. If it's not enough(context) I can attach a scan of the document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a document transferring a piece of land, or some rights in a piece of land.

*As the whole now subsists* is a formal way of saying “In its entire current state, in the entire condition it now presents”.

*With all its rights members and appurtenances* (in ordinary non-legal writing there would be a comma after *rights*) specifies that current state in more detail by enumerating what is to be included: all the rights which the vendor holds in the property, all the elements that are part of the property, and everything else that has any legal connection with the property. (This sort of enumerative phrase is common in the Anglo law tradition.)

*Without exception or reserve of any kind on the part of the Vendor* means that the Vendor does not except or ‘hold back’ any element of those ‘rights members and appurtenances’.

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer. I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

As the whole *(of the document)* now remains in force *(subsists)*  with all its rights, members and anything belonging/related to the subject of the document *(Appurtenances)* without any objections or anticipation of future needs (exception or reserve) of any kind on the part of the seller (vendor).

You can double check what I've said here;

http://thelawdictionary.org/

Comment: I think what is described here is a property being transferred, 'with a building &c', rather than a document; the 'deed' is mentioned only as the governing authority for the 'servitude' to which the property is subject.

Comment: @StoneyB That would be the **subject** of the document. The additional information wasn't available at the time of writing my answer.

Comment: Strange, the current context was added 28 minutes ago, and you answered 14 minutes ago, as I am writing this. _The whole_ does certainly not refer to the document in which this sentence appear, but to the building or land that is being sold.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, your comment is strange indeed.

Comment: @JoeDark: Strange is my middle name. But there was no information added to the question after you wrote your answer. So your claim that the additional information was not available at the time you wrote your answer is simply incorrect.